# only works if the content of author.name is exact or leftover words

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The bot reacts only when the content of `author.name` is exact, but if it has an extra word it doesn't work, but it doesn't throw an error
example:

```js
const ListClaims = ["rick sanchez", "alex", "juan"];
```

`rick sanchez` has no error because it is exact to `ListClaims`

`rick sanchez morty` has an error because it has additional letters which is `morty`,

```
    var ListClaims = ["rick sanchez","alex","juan"];

    if(message.embeds.length >= 0) 
    // Check if the Message has embed or not
    {
      let embed = message.embeds
      // console.log(embed) just a console.log
      for(let i = 0; i < embed.length; i++)
      {
        if (!embed[i] || !embed[i].author || embed[i].author.name === null) return;
        // check each embed if it has setAuthor or not, if it doesnt then do nothing
        {
        if(embed[i].author.name.toLowerCase().includes(ListClaims))
        // check each embed if it includes word
        {
          message.react('')
        }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clearly state what the goal is? Your question is just a statement of what currently happens.

Comment: I have formatted your post, but the snippet contains some errors (ghost brackets) so I didn't touch your code, you have to fix it yourself as I don't want to break your application :)

Answer (score 0):

I've reformated your code, so it's simpler and easier to read. If you give a better example of what you want to happen, I can edit this answer to solve it better.

```js
function messageHandler() {

  const msg = {
    embeds: [
      { author: { name: "alex" }},
      { author: { name: "john"}},
      { author: { name: "rick sanchez morty"}},
    ]
  }

  const listClaims = ["rick sanchez", "alex", "juan"];

  // 0 is falsey by default, so you dont have to check if it's  == 0.
  if (!msg.embeds.length) return;
  // Check if the Message has embed or not

  msg.embeds.forEach(embed => {
    // "", null and undefined are also falsey, so we don't need to check them.
    // also this if statement is not needed, since you can just do Array.includes().
    if (!embed.author.name) return;

    // .includes() is an array method, not a string method, so you have to do Array.includes(target), not target.includes(array).
    if (listClaims.includes(embed.author.name.toLowerCase())) message.react('');
  });
}

const message = {
  react: console.log
};

messageHandler()
```